# Javascript class constructor and prototype

Tags: javascript

```
function operation(a, b){                                                                     
this.width = a;  
this.height = b;    
}

var pro1 = new operation(10, 15);  
pro1.color = "black";
```

can someone tell me please in this code, what is constructor what is class and what is prototype

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes
You can get more info about classes and constructor in the above link

Comment: `operation` is the constructor function (ought to be Capitalized for convention) . There is no class and you are not using the prototype of the constructor function.

Comment: ok. can you give me please one example what exactly is constructor and what exactly is prototype in JS?

Comment: Unlike a particular problem this is a wide topic all by itself. So it might be slightly complicated and confusing for you to understand the fundamental concepts of JS properly just by collecting fragmented information from various users of SO. I would advise you the best book i had ever read on JS fundamentals. [Go and read it](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2014/02/25/now-shipping-principles-of-object-oriented-javascript/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no class in JS, but often a function, which will be used to instantiate new objects using `new` operator is referred to as `constructor/class`. So in your example, this `operation` function is `constructor/class`:

```
function operation(a, b){}
```

It's a good convention to capitalize the name of your constructors. You may see in ES6 the word `class` used like that:

```
class Operation {

}
```

However, it's still a function and it's added for convenience:

```
typeof Operation === "function"; // true
```

Prototype is simply a JavaScript object, that is linked to the other JavaScript object using internal link (usually it's **proto**). So, you have an object:

```
var o = {method: function(){}}
```

It can be linked to other object like this:

```
var another = {}
Object.setPrototypeOf(another, o);
```

Once linked, you can access properties of the prototype object from the linked object like this:

```
another.method(); // will work
```

Prototypes can be added automatically by setting them to `.prototype` property of the `constructor/class`. In your code, you have not defined a prototype yourself in your code, however, it's still created by JS engine and you can see it using this code:

```
operation.prototype
```

When created, it points to the function itself:

```
operation.prototype === operation; // true
```

Comment: OK. now i now what is constructor/class...What is PROTOTYPE in JS?

Comment: @Raspolozen, updated. Don't forget you can accept my answer if it answers your question.

Comment: im not a programmer...and i dont have a programmer knowlege of this kind a things...i understand what is constructor/class but i dont have any idea what PROTOTYPE is, and what is that mean in JS??

Comment: `constructor` is a function in JavaScript. I can't explain you all JavaScript here. I've given you guidelines and basic explanation. Now explore things :)

Comment: what is PROTOTYPE? constructor i understand

Comment: it's a simple JavaScript object. `var o = {}; // I am simple object`, and now `Object.setPrototypeOf(o1, o); // now I am a prototype of 'o1' object`